# How can I undo "unstage changes"

Tags: git

By mistake I got rid of some of my work by clicking "unstage changes" in vs code, after they were already staged. Is there any way to get them back?

Comment: Undoing staged changes shouldn't get rid of the work done. You should be able to stage the changes again. --- Otherwise, if the work was undone, then you have lost it. Remember: commit often.

Answer (score 2):

Yes - when you stage changes, the file is added to the object database and a reference to that file is recorded in the index.  You can use the [`git-recover` tool](https://www.edwardthomson.com/blog/introducing_git_recover.html) to identify files that were added to the repository (staged) but are no longer referenced, and recover them to the working directory.